# trying to create my first table in a postgres database on GCP but nothing is happening

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, psql

I am currently trying to import a .csv into a postgres database on Google Cloud Platform but I'm having some trouble. Here's what's going on.

I have created a bucket and uploaded the .csv file to the cloud storage. I have created a user with the right permissions. I have created the database. I have started the database and have successfully connected to it in the cloud shell on the platform.

I've tried typing in `postgres=> CREATE TABLE`, nothing happens.
I've tried typing in `postgres-> CREATE TABLE--member info` thinking maybe I have to add a table name, nothing happens.
I've tried just naming the table in the import and it has an error.

Any ideas why it's letting me connect to the database but won't let me create a table?

Comment: can you please post the actual CREATE table statements and the responses the system provided?

Comment: This would be good place to start [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html)